# Upload multiple files with php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, file, upload

Hello everyone and I hope you can help me

The problem is this, I have a form with the following code:

```
<form action="uploadernoticias.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" class="nice" id="form1">
    <h2>Insertar Noticias</h2>
    <p class="left">
      <label>Titulo</label>
        <input name="caption" type="text" class="inputText" id="caption" />
      <label>Imagen/Foto</label>
      <input type="file" name="uploadedfile" id="uploadedfile" class="inputText" />
    </p>
    <p class="right">
    <label>Description:</label>
        <textarea name="contenido" cols="" rows="10" class="inputText_wide" id="contenido"></textarea>
        <br clear="all" />
        <button class="green" type="submit">Listo! - Subir Noticias</button>

    </p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </form>
```

And the file uploadernoticias.php:

```
<?php

/*##################--[Obteniendo datos del formulario - Propiedades]*/

// Nombre
$caption = $_POST['caption'];
// Contenido
$contenido= $_POST['contenido'];

/*##################--[Definiendo la carpeta imagenes para las Propiedades]*/

$target_path = "../imagenes/noticias/";

/*##################--[Seteando las imagenes]*/
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 
$file_path = basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 
$file_size = basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['size']); 
if ($file_size > '20452525'){
header('Location: gallery.php?id=error');
} 
else
{
/*##################--[Informando si se subio correctamente entonces..]*/
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    //echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    //" has been uploaded<br><br>Link: <a href=\"http://www.thetastingroomokc.com/gallery/". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])  ."\">http://www.thetastingroomokc.com/gallery/". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])  ."</a>";

/*##################--[Insertar en la base de datos]*/  
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO noticias VALUES ('', '$caption', '$contenido', '$file_path')");

    //echo $file_size.' is how big your file is. It was transferred.';

/*##################--[Luego, enviar a una pagina]*/    
    header('Location: noticias.php');

} else{
   echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
}

?>
```

The problem is that it gives me no error, nor rises to the database or upload images to the folders on the server.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you and hope you can help me

Comment: Not getting any error messages? Add your own! Trace the code with debug statements to isolate the problem.

Comment: Seemed to work fine here, try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` after `<?php` and see if it generates any errors.
Also, I noticed you are uploading it to a folder with in the parent folder (../) is that supposed to be?

Comment: You should add a couple of "breakpoints", try var_dump( $_FILES ) before the conditional, it is probably a problem with permission of the folder.

Comment: ´Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/sitios/public_html/farmland/farmland/ad5/uploadernoticias.php:3) in /home/sitios/public_html/farmland/farmland/ad5/uploadernoticias.php on line 36´

Comment: The file is in Ad5 uploader.php / and goes to the images folder / properties folder is outside the Ad5

And my computer works perfectly! but up to my domain is not working as it should, try putting .. /imagenes/noticias news without the /.

Also I have error_reporting (E_ALL) and I get error

Comment: It gave permissions to the folder, from imagenes 777 and 777 and also to news no solution

Comment: I saw the line 36 is:

'header (' Location: noticias.php '),' then we get:

'# header (' Location: noticias.php '),' and there does not give me any error even if I put error_reporting (E_ALL)

Comment: Also, I have set ini_set ('display_errors', 'On'), and now does not give me any error,

that more data needed to diagnose the problem?

Comment: Assuming the upload succeeded is a BAD way to go. at bare minimum you should have `if ($_FILES['uploadedfile']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) { ... }` before proceeding.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you don't have write permission in target_path. Did you check it? Probably you don't see any error message because you have display_errors disabled (in php.ini). You could activate display_errors or activate logging in your server:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors

http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors

If you don't have access to configuration files, you can try this in your script:

```
ini_set('display_errors','On');
```

Comment: Also, I have set ini_set ('display_errors', 'On'), and now does not give me any error,

that more data needed to diagnose the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try applying the right permissions to the upload folder, in most ftp browsers it's right click on the folder > file attributes or permissions, and set them to 777.
Through SSH this would be: `chmod -Rf 777 foldername`